# How to set what gets return in my Reducer for React Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm setting up Redux in my React environment to be able to move user selection data between components. I want to be able to get the `cart` value found in my `Webshop.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{ Connect } from 'react-redux';

import Shirt from './shirt.jpg';


export default class addCart extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {value: 'medium'}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
        console.log(cart);
    } 

    change(e){
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    itemSelection(){
        let userOrder = {price:0,item:"",size:""};
        let userItem = "";
        if (userItem == "shirt1") {
           let itemPrice = 20.00;
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <li id="Productlist">
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={Shirt}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>  
                      <img src={Shirt}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I then want to get this `Cart` value and move it to other components using Redux. So this is my Redux `store.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';


var initialState = {
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    createLogger(),
    thunkMiddleware
  )
);
export default store;
```

This is my `actions.js`:

```
export const ADD_CART = 'ADD_CART';

export function addCart(){
    return {
        type: ADD_CART,
        payload: item
    }
};
```

and my `reducers.js`:

```
import {ADD_CART} from './actions';

export default reducer;

function rootReducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type)
        case ADD_CART:
            return  
}
```

To link my store to my components, I wrapped all of my components inside a  `<Provider>` tag in my `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import Webshop from 'views/webshop';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';



ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={ hashHistory }>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path='Webshop' component={ Webshop } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
            </Route>
        </Provider> 
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

How can I set what get returned in my reducer so I can pass `cart` to other components in my app?

Comment: Your reducers should (generally) return another state object.

Comment: This is what I'm having problems applying to my code..how should I use state to get the data I want? @OliverCharlesworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your `addCart` Component using `connect` from 'react-redux' and give it an `onCartAdd` prop to dispatch the `addCart` action to your Store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { addCart } from './actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Shirt from './shirt.jpg';

class WebShop extends Component {
  ...

  handleClick() {
    let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
    this.props.onCartAdd(cart);
  }

  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onCartAdd: (cart) => {
      dispatch(addCart(cart));
    },
  }
}

export deafult connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
```

`addCart` in your 'actions.js' needs to take `item` as an argument:

```
export const ADD_CART = 'ADD_CART';

export function addCart(iten){
    return {
        type: ADD_CART,
        payload: item
    }
};
```

[Usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) explains in more detail how to customize `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "addCart"`, I assume this is due to having the same name on my action function as well as my function the handles the click..also, do I need the reducers file with this method?I so what is the value I return?

Comment: Fixed that error by adding an alias..however I get this error `Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.` because my reducer function does not return anything..

Comment: I understand that in your example `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {` works as my reducer , so I deleted my `reducers.js` file. Now I get this error: `app.js:831 Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(addCart)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(addCart)".`

Comment: "I understand that in your example `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {` works as my reducer , so I deleted my reducers.js file." That is incorrect; you still need a reducer. The reducer receives actions and returns the necessary modifications to your store.

Comment: I modified my code to call the class `WebShop` and passed that to `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

The data of your app that is going to be used by multiple components should be added to `store`. Then you can access this data from any component by using `connect`.

If you want `cart` to be accessed by other components, you should add it in your store,

i.e.

```
var initialState = {
  cart: "medium",
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
}
```

then you can use this value in any component by using `connect`.

And in your root reducer change this value when you dispatch the action,

```
import {ADD_CART} from './actions';

export default reducer;

function rootReducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type)
        case ADD_CART:
            return {
             ...state,
             cart: action.payload
             }
}
```